# SBApplication no communication

Tags: swift, spotify, scripting-bridge

I`m trying to control the Spotify using my custom switch app. Creation works OK but each communicaction ends with nil or undefined value. For example this snipped prints "??":

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    let player = SBApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.spotify.client")! as SpotifyApplication

    switch player.playerState {
        case .paused:
            print("paused")
        case .playing:
            print("playing")
        case .stopped:
            print("stopped")
        default:
            print("??")
    }
}
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: fix syntax '...but each communication...'

Comment: Did you switch on the Apple Events capability? Did you turn off sandboxing? etc etc

Comment: Don't you try to create `player` as an AppDelegate's variable?

Comment: @matt Apple Events is checked and sandboxing is disabled (removed)

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov yes I tried that but with no success

Comment: And did you put in the Apple Events Sending Usage Description in your Info.plist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the @matt I found the solution - Info.plist was missing "Privacy - AppleEvents Sending Usage Description"

Comment: Link to key description https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsappleeventsusagedescription